# Not able to send many images to server using vector<T> in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am changing the signature of a function having default argument char* to vector in C++. The role of function with default argument char* is to take out the image name of an image file, then read that image file and send to the server. This function is only capable of sending one image file. So, I went for vector to send multiple images at once. But, somewhere I am missing on something which I am not able to find out. If anyone can please help.

Function with default parameter of char*:

```
void fileSend(char *fpath)
{
    // Extract only filename from given path.
    char filename[50];
    int i = strlen(fpath);
    for (; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (fpath[i - 1] == '\\')
            break;
    }
    for (int j = 0; i <= (int)strlen(fpath); i++)
    {
        filename[j++] = fpath[i];
    }

    ifstream myFile(fpath, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
    int size = (int)myFile.tellg();
    myFile.close();

    char filesize[10]; itoa(size, filesize, 10);
    send(sock, filename, strlen(filename), 0);
    char rec[32] = ""; 
    recv(sock, rec, 32, 0);

    send(sock, filesize, strlen(filesize), 0);
    recv(sock, rec, 32, 0);

    FILE *fr = fopen(fpath, "rb");

    while (size > 0)
    {
        char buffer[1030];

        if (size >= 1024)
        {
            fread(buffer, 1024, 1, fr);
            send(sock, buffer, 1024, 0);
            recv(sock, rec, 32, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            fread(buffer, size, 1, fr);
            buffer[size] = '\0';
            send(sock, buffer, size, 0);
            recv(sock, rec, 32, 0);
        }
        size -= 1024;
    }
    fclose(fr);
}
```

Function with default parameter of vector:

```
void fileSend(vector<string> fnames)
    {
        char *filename;
        for (int k = 0; k < fnames.size(); k++)
        {
            int i = fnames[k].length;

            for (; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (fnames[k][i - 1] == '\\')
                    break;
            }
            for (int j = 0; i <= fnames[k].length(); i++)
            {
                filename[j++] = fnames[k][i];
            }

            ifstream myFile(fnames[k], ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
            int size = (int)myFile.tellg();
            myFile.close();

            char filesize[10]; itoa(size, filesize, 10);
            send(sock, filename, strlen(filename), 0);
            char rec[32] = "";
            recv(sock, rec, 32, 0);

            send(sock, filesize, strlen(filesize), 0);
            recv(sock, rec, 32, 0);

            FILE *fr = fopen(fnames[k], "rb");

            while (size > 0)
            {
                char buffer[1030];

                if (size >= 1024)
                {
                    fread(buffer, 1024, 1, fr);
                    send(sock, buffer, 1024, 0);
                    recv(sock, rec, 32, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    fread(buffer, size, 1, fr);
                    buffer[size] = '\0';
                    send(sock, buffer, size, 0);
                    recv(sock, rec, 32, 0);
                }
                size -= 1024;
            }
            fclose(fr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What default argument?

Comment: You're calling `send()` using an uninitialized `filename` variable. Yes, you copy values but you never allocated  memory. Anything may happen. Do you move to C++? Drop completely C strings

Comment: In the second function void fileSend(vector<string> fnames), it gives an error in line : " int i = fnames[k].length; " - error C3867: 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::length': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::length' to create a pointer to member
And also some warnings like:
warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch 
This warning is in line : " for (int k = 0; k < fnames.size(); k++) "

Comment: @beginner `length` is a function; write `length()`.